# Open page in new window and hide few controls HTML

Tags: jquery, html

I want to open a new window and hide one of the div in new window, but I am not able to hide it.

Here is the scenario -

1. I have a page "p1" with a left navbar.
2. I want to open "p1" from a different page "p2", but without "navbar". I want to hide the navbar on "p1" based on a condition.

Below is my code

```
var win = window.open("p1.html", "mypage", 'width=400');            
win.document.getElementById("left-sidebar").setAttribute("style", "display:none;");
```

Any idea how to do it?

Comment: Your question is unclear. Please elaborate and provide HTML codes as well so we can replicate the issue :)

Comment: Possible failure reasons: CORS, document not ready, typo. But only you can check these

Comment: Is "url" in your code?  Or is there a real URL?

Comment: its url to one of my page.

Comment: need to bind a load handler to new window so element exists when code runs. It won't be there the instant after you call `open()`

Comment: Can you help me with a sample or an example site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found a way to do this and below is how I did it-

1. I created another page popup.html.
2. I created an iframe inside popup.html.
3. I then opened the desired url in iframe and controlled the content of the iframe in popup.html.

**1. P1.html**

```
<html>
<head>      
    <script>
    </script>
</head>
<body>
Page 1
</body>
```

**2. P2.html**

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            window.open("popup.html?http://localhost/TestPage/p1.html","","");
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>Page 2
</body>
```

**3. Popup.html**

```
<html>
<head>  
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        
            $("#iframe").attr("src", window.location.search.substring(1));
                
            $("#iframe").load(function() {
                var head = $(this).contents().find("head");
                var css = '<style type="text/css">' +
                            'body{background-color:blue}; ' +
                          '</style>';
                $(head).append(css);            
        
            });
        
    });
            </script>
</head>
<body>
<iframe id="iframe"></iframe>
</body>
```

**Result**

[image]

Hope it helps someone :)